# php ImageMagick exec -draw text doesn't work as expected - special characters

Tags: php, text, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

```
exec($IM_path."convert
    -size 800x300 xc:black  
    -font ".$linktottf."
    -pointsize 16
    -draw \"fill white stroke none decorate underline text 580,28 Kühle Frische, not working\"
    output.png");
```

The "draw text"-part in the code above doesn't work. the output.png displays only "Khle" … so there must be a problem with Special Characters, Whitespaces, Quotes, …

I tried a lot (escaping, different quotes, backslashes, …)

I've lost a lot of time now … so this is why I hope you could help me.
Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the quotes drawn as well you need to enclose them in a different set of quotes, double quotes wrapped in single quotes.

```
label:'\"fill white stroke none decorate underline text 580,28 Kühle Frische, not working\"'
```

As for the special characters try saving your script in unix utf-8 format (editors like Textpad have options for saving files as these when showing the save dialog, similar editors should have the same option).

And set the system LANG to use utf

`LANG=en_US.utf-8;`

```
exec("LANG=en_US.utf-8; ".$IM_path."convert -size 800x300 xc:black -font ".$linktottf." -pointsize 16 label:'\"fill white stroke none decorate underline text 580,28 Kühle Frische, not working\"' output.png");
```

Looks like you want 'label' and not draw. also it needs to be on one line otherwise it will interpret it as separate commands

Comment: hm.. your code does not work. are you sure that the LANG=en_US.utf-8;-part is at the right position .. and the quotes at the draw-line .. they'll break the string/cmd

Comment: yea wasnt fully done editing, the lang should be in the front of the path, wasnt paying attention that you were including the path for the convert.

Comment: oh sorry. now.. there is no output. if I delete the LANG-part there is one, but without text. so it still doesn't work ..

Comment: ok you need `label` or `caption` or similar others, not `-draw` to draw text, http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/

Comment: And dont forget to put the whole command on one line otherwise it iterperets the parts on new lines to be other commands.

Comment: and change your font color, you have the background black, and text gets rendered as black by default so

Comment: but now it's something totally different .. LANG=en_US.utf-8; still doesn't work! the "ü" is not displayed

Comment: did you also save the php script to utf-8 format like i mentioned?

Comment: i inserted header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); but it has no effect .. as long as i am using "LANG=en_US.utf-8;" it doesn't work .. means nothing works!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32507/discussion-between-patrick-evans-and-john-doe-smith)

Comment: Hey @JohnDoeSmith: What did you do to get it working. For same thing is happening. Command is working from command prompt but not from php.